# Creating a scrollable/rewritable terminal/stdout interface with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, terminal

When I print to my terminal in Node.js, I use `console.log` to output a new line of text. However, there are some applications that dynamically update the same lines of console output, instead of just adding new ones. A popular example of this is the ASCII loading bar that appears in `wget` or `scp`.

There are some applications that fill the entire terminal window with dynamic output. `ngrok` is an example of this:

[image: ngrok]

This application updates the information above dynamically.

Are there frameworks that will help me create a similar dynamic output in Node.js? Does this have a name?

Comment: Check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-with-statusbar

Answer (score 10):

Well maybe this is too much for what you need.. but I'm going to give you some options of tools that you can use..

A better option to just use a console.log It would be using colors instead:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/color
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk

If you need prompt questions to the user:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer

For create command lines, you have:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

For terminal interfaces you have these:

- https://github.com/chjj/blessed

  Then on the top of that one you have this one:
- https://github.com/Yomguithereal/react-blessed

Those are amazing tools.. I'm using them for my project and they just rock. There are some others.. tell if you need more hehe

Answer (score 3):

You can try this module: [ansi.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ansi)